# Xamarin Studio eat too much memory of iMac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have installed Xamarin Studio 6.2 (build 1413) in iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, Late 2015, 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3, 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5). When I start Xamarin Studio, my iMac is goes down. I found in Activity Monitor, Xamarin studio eat 7-12 GB of memory.

[image]

Please help me to find out solution.

Thank You

Comment: Known "issue": Make sure you are using the latest version, review the release notes: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.2/xamarin.studio_6.2/

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover for reply, I have update my xamarin studio, but my issue is not solved. I am using Alpha version.

Comment: As I said, this is a known issue that is being worked on, file a bug report with your solution/project details : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by updating Xamarin.Studio and XCode. And It is working fine now.